# How to use SIFT detector and SURF descriptor in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use a SIFT detector and SURF descriptor. However, I just know how to use a SIFT / SURF detector and descriptor to compute similarity of two images but not the combination of them.

Here is the code for SIFT detector and descriptor:

```
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
img_a = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
img_b = cv2.imread('b.jpg')
kp_des_a = sift.detectAndCompute(img_a , None)[1]
kp_des_b = sift.detectAndCompute(img_b , None)[1]
bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = bf.knnMatch(kp_des_a, kp_des_b, k=2)
good = [m for m, n in matches if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance]
score = len(good)
```

How to use SIFT detector and SURF descriptor?

Comment: I haven't used python interface. So I could be wrong here. But you can try detecting keypoints using `sift.detect()`. Then try using `surf.compute()` to get the descriptors.

Comment: Thank you, dhanushka. Sometimes, there are only one element in `matches` instead of two. Why and how to tackle it?

Comment: Please check knnMatch documentation. It says `Each matches[i] is k or less matches for the same query descriptor. k: Count of best matches found per each query descriptor or less if a query descriptor has less than k possible matches in total.`